# How to fully stretch 2 embeded divs?

Tags: html, css

How can I fully stretch two `<div>`s to be `50%` wide? Prepared [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cdydq/2/).

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="left">left</div>
   <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div.container {
   width: 100%;
}

div.left, div.right {
   display:inline;
   width:50%;
}
```

Comment: `float:left;` does the trick. Don't forget a clearfix afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
div.container {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
div.left, div.right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}
```

[**Updated jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hallaji/cdydq/8/)

**Or:**

```
div.container {
    width: 100%;
}
div.left, div.right {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

[**Updated jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hallaji/cdydq/16/)

Answer (score 2):

There is multiple ways of doing that. You could apply css like this.

```
div.left, div.right {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cdydq/14/

Here is another method that may render the required reults.

```
div.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
div.left {
    position: relative;
    width:50%;
}
div.right {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:50%;
    width:50%;
    top:0
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cdydq/18/

Answer (score 2):

One approach: Use `inline-block` and `box-sizing: border-box` (the latter if you have borders)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/cdydq/15/)

CSS:

```
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.container{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

div.left, div.right {
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">left</div><div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Note: the lack of space between the two divs in purposeful.  A space between two inline elements is meaningful.